# (RSS Feed) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, rss, feed, blogger

I am trying to pick content from a Google Blogger Feed that is http://testdevchuli.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?redirect=false&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=exeRSSpostReader&max-results=500 through using the JavaScript code at http://testdevchuli.blogspot.com/ where you can see the error through Inspect Element section where there is only one red warning that is...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
exeRSSpostReaderMain @ (index):1342
exeRSSpostReader @ (index):1313
(anonymous function) @ default?redirect=false&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=exeRSSpostReader&max-results=5…:2
```

So why its happening...??? Here is my full code from the upper link...

```
<script>
function exeRSSpostReader(json){
//<![CDATA[ 
//exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, DivisionId, Label, PostsVisible, ImageVisibility, SummaryVisibility, SummaryCharcters);
//DivisionId: Id of the division in which the result should shown.
//Label: Specific Label, Set &quot;&quot; for all posts.
//PostsVisible: No of posts shown in final result.
//ImageVisibility: Set true if you want thumbnails else set false.
//SummaryVisibility: Set true if you want summary else set false.
//SummaryCharcters: No of character shown in summary.
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'latest_post', '', 3, true, true, 150);
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'first_label', 'Dashain Song', 3, true, true, 150);
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'second_label', 'Modern Song', 6, true, true, 150);
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'third_label', 'Nepali Movie', 4, true, true, 150);
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'fourth_label', 'Nepali Movie', 4, true, true, 150);
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'fifth_label', 'Nepali Movie', 4, true, true, 150);
exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, 'sixth_label', 'Nepali Movie', 5, true, true, 150);
}
//]]>
</script>
<script style='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
function exeRSSpostReaderMain(json, postArea, labelTxt, visiblePosts, imageVisible, summaryVisible, summaryChar) {
    var noOfTotalPosts  = 500;
    var outputDiv = postArea;
    var postLabel = labelTxt;
    var numPosts = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
    var indexPosts = new Array();
    var pstChk = 0;
    var resultStr = '';
    var resultStr = '<ul style="height:100%;background:#fff;">';
    for (var i = 0; i < numPosts; ++i) {
        indexPosts[i] = i;
    }
    if (noOfTotalPosts > numPosts) {
        noOfTotalPosts = numPosts;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < noOfTotalPosts; ++i) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[indexPosts[i]];
        var postTitle =  entry.title.$t;
        for (var k = 0; k <  entry.link.length; k++) {
            if ( entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                postURL =  entry.link[k].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ("content" in entry) {
            var postContent = entry.content.$t
        }
        s = postContent;
        a = s.indexOf("<img");
        b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
        c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
        d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
        if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
            var imageUrl = d
        } else var imageUrl = 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cXUE46Oenac/U6rONTOCYuI/AAAAAAAAQTw/r_WI91TMLpk/s400/Images_no_image.gif';
        var img = '';
        if (imageVisible == true) {
        var img = '<a href="'+postURL+'"><img src="'+imageUrl+'" alt="' + postTitle + '" title="' + postTitle + '" /></a>';
        }
        var labels = '';
        if (!entry.category){
            var noLabel = "No Label In This Post";
        } else {
            for(var lblNo = 0; lblNo < entry.category.length; lblNo++){
                labels += entry.category[lblNo].term + ', ';
            }
        }
        if (labels.search(postLabel) >= 0 && pstChk < visiblePosts){
        resultStr += '<li><div id="exe_post_container">'  + img + '<h2 ><a href="'+postURL+'">' + postTitle + '</h2></a></h2><p>';
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        postContent = postContent.replace(re, "");
        if (summaryVisible == true) {
            if (postContent.length < summaryChar) {
                resultStr += postContent + '</p>';
            } else {
                postContent = postContent.substring(0, summaryChar);
                var quoteEnd_gal = postContent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                postContent = postContent.substring(0, quoteEnd_gal);
                resultStr += postContent + '...</p>';
            }
        }
         resultStr += '</div></li>';
         pstChk++;
        }
    }
    resultStr += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById(outputDiv).innerHTML += resultStr;
}
function readMoreWidget() {
var var1 = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerHTML;var var2 = var1.search('href="http://www.exeideas.net" target="_blank">EXEIdeas');if (var2 == '-1'){alert('This Template Is Designed By EXEIdeas(www.exeideas.net)');}
}
window.onload = readMoreWidget;
//]]>
</script>
<script src='http://testdevchuli.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?redirect=false&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=exeRSSpostReader&max-results=500'></script>
```

Comment: The returned result is enclosed within the callback function of exeRSSpostReader(); so you need to extract the JSON data from here i.e. exeRSSpostReader( js ) { return JSON_parse(js); }

Comment: @jeff I am using the below code to fetch the title. Is this wrong?
`var entry = json.feed.entry[indexPosts[i]];`
`var postTitle =  entry.title.$t;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to running a loop of getting the posts more the your RSS feed link have. For example if you have 100 posts in your RSS Feed and you are running a loop of 101 then while running the iteration no 101 then it will through the error while trying to get the data from null space so try to less your loop count.